# Kafka Streams: Aggregation results for key differ based on the number of threads

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I've got an input topic with 50 partitions and I'm trying to count the total amount of messages received using Kafka Streams. Consider the following topology.

```
var inputStream = builder.stream("input-topic", Consumed.with(...));


inputStream
    // Grouping by a constant key here for global aggregation.
    .groupBy((k, v) -> 1L, Serialized.with(...))
    .count()
    .toStream()
    .foreach((k, v) -> System.out.println("Count updated to: " + v));

...

// For simplicity, let's consider the cache size to be zero.
props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, 0);
```

Bizarre things happen when I start playing around with the number of threads.

In the simplest example with 1 thread, the count grows nicely with the number of messages received.

Set the number of threads to e.g. 50, and a few things happen:

1. The count grows very very slowly.
2. The initial growth seems to be logarithmic.
3. When there is a pause in the new messages arriving, the count continues to grow linearly.
4. It never seems to reach the desired value.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, please?

Comment: Does it start to go wrong at 50? It's fine with 1, but what about 2 threads? 4? 10? etc

Comment: Why do you need more thread? If you want to do a global count, and all records have the same key, they will be processed by a single thread anyway.